# Trying to read JSON file within a Python package

Tags: python, package, setuptools, python-packaging

I am in the process of packaging up a python package that I'll refer to as `MyPackage`.

The package structure is:

```
MyPackage/
    script.py
    data.json
```

The `data.json` file comprises cached data that is read in `script.py`.

I have figured out how to include data files (use of setuptools `include_package_data=True` and to also include path to data file in the `MANIFEST.in` file) but now when I pip install this package and import the installed MyPackage (currently testing install by `pip` from the GitHub repository) I get a `FileNotFound` exception (data.json) in the script that is to utilize MyPackage. However, I see that the `data.json` file is indeed installed in `Lib/site-packages/MyPackage`.

Am I doing something wrong here by trying to read in a `json` file in a package?

Note that in `script.py` I am attempting to read `data.json` as `open('data.json', 'r')`

Am I screwing up something regarding the path to the data file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you share your code? It will be easier to help you if you do.

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message as well as a [mcve].**

Answer (score 32):

You're not screwing something up, accessing package resources is just a little tricky - largely because they can be packaged in formats where your .json might strictly speaking not exist as an actual file on the system where your package is installed (e.g. as [zip-app](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0441/)). The right way to access your data file is not by specifying a path to it (like `"MyPackage/data.json"`), but by accessing it as a resource of your installed package (like `"MyPackage.data.json"`). The distinction might seem pedantic, but it can matter a lot.

Anyway, the access should be done using the builtin [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) module:

```py
import importlib.resources
import json

with importlib.resources.open_text("MyPackage", "data.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)  
# you should be able to access 'data' like a dictionary here
```

---

If you happen to work on a python version lower than 3.7, you will have to install it as [`importlib_resources`](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-resources/) from pyPI.

Comment: Ah awesome! I just saw this after I posted my answer. I will try this, thank you! It's funny, I thought discretizing a piece of an existing script would be relatively easy but here I am nearly 2 hours later... ha

Comment: yeah, packaging code can turn into a mess really quickly =)

Comment: I'm wondering if something has changed in Python 3.9? An exact copy of your example code crashes for me with `AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'read'` The documentation suggests that "The context manager provides a pathlib.Path object" so I'm assuming it's working as intended, but that would invalidate your example. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MantasKandratavicius uhm.. no, you're right. It seems I uploaded buggy code and still managed to get a bunch of upvotes for it. `json.load` expects a file handle, not a path object, so you need to call `open()` there first. It's fixed now, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Instead of using the double with's you can also use `importlib.resources.open_text`, as in `with importlib.resources.open_text("MyPackage", "data.json") as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)`

Comment: @boudewijn21 I didn't know that function, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by getting the 'relative path' to where the package is.

```py
self.data = self.load_data(path=os.path.join(
                os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
                'data.json'))
```

> `load_data` just reads the data file

Any constructive criticism is still very much welcome. Not trying to write stupid code if I can't help it :)

Comment: If this is a simple package that you have full control over, doing it like this will probably be good enough. One case where it might fail is if you install the package as a zipped archive.